# How do I print a variable in a shell script without altering trailing newline (if there is one)?

Tags: shell, printf, echo, newline, sh

I have a shell script that takes input from another shell script. The stream gets piped in on stdin.

I need to capture all the bytes of the stdin stream to a single variable in the shell script. Then, perform some operations on it, and send it back out over stdout.

The problem I have is that sometimes there is a trailing newline character in the input file, but sometimes there is not. If there is not, then I do not want to add one. If there is a trailing newline, however, I want to preserve that.

The problem is that no matter what I try, the system either always outputs WITHOUT a trailing newline (as in the case of `printf`) or it always outputs WITH a newline (as in the case of `echo`).

Please tell me what is the name of a process (not `echo` or `printf`) that simply takes a variable and streams it out, verbatim, byte for byte, over stdout. I have tried all possible options for `printf` and none of them works to preserve trailing newlines.

Please note I am not interested in why `printf` and `echo` both cannot do this one simple thing. Unless you can show me a portable way across unix platforms to use those commands to do what I ask, in which case I'm all ears :D

Comment: One problem you'll have: if you use `$(command substitution)` to capture the output, you won't know if there's a trailing newline or not -- [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) explicitly *deletes trailing newlines*.

Comment: OK but I get the same behavior if instead of command substitution, I use tildes, as for example `var=\`cat /dev/stdin\`` or of course simply `var=\`tee\``.

Comment: backticks are command substitution syntax too. Same problem.

Comment: OK so how do you avoid the trailing newline being stripped?

Comment: You could redirect the output to a file, or you could use a language (python/perl/...) that does not do this.

Comment: the solution as pointed out by chepner is to append a character to the end of the input stream while inside the command substitution then remove it when you're done processing the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard trick is to append a sentinel character inside the command substitution, then remove it. That way, nothing preceding the sentinel is stripped.

```
$ x=$(printf "Newlines stripped\n\n\n")
$ echo "$x"
Newlines stripped
$ x=$(printf "Newlines preserved\n\n\n"; printf "X")
$ x=${x%X}
$ echo "$x"
Newlines preserved


$
```

You can also use the `read` builtin in a loop to append one line from standard input at a time to your variable, avoiding the issue of command substitution stripping the newlines.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    x="$x$line"
done
```

Once you have safely preserved any newline characters in the output, you can remove the last one, if present, then add it back. This way, if the string did not originally have a newline, it does now; and if it did have one or more newlines at the end, you have not changed the number of trailing newlines.

```
x="${x%"
"}
"
```

Since `echo` itself appends a newline to the output, you can print *just* the variable's value using `printf` instead. The `%s` format string instructs `printf` to interpret its argument literally.

```
printf %s "$x"
```

(Some versions of `echo` may support a `-n` option to suppress the additional newline, but it is not entirely portable.)

Comment: OK sorry I marked your answer correct in haste. There is one problem with it though: `echo "$x"` adds a newline! I found that `printf '%s' "$x"` works flawlessly however. If you update your answer I'll approve it again :D

Comment: Will do; the `echo` isn't really part of the answer; I just use that to output the value of `$x` in each case so you can see where newlines were and were not removed.

Comment: Well the question does ask "how do I *print* a variable..." so I think that it *is* really part of the answer :D